# Ionic/Cordova: hiding status bar for iPad

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, hide, statusbar

I am working with **Ionic framework** and noticed this issue when emulating the app on **ios**.

If I try to emulate my app on iPhone the status bar is hidden, but if I try to emulate on iPad the status bar overlaps with my app screen.

To emulate I use this command:

```
ionic emulate ios --target="iPad-Air"
```

This is an example image that shows what I mean by overlap. The "TOP OF MY CONTENT" overlaps with status bar.

[image]

Here is the example that does not overlap:

[image]

And this image shows what I mean by hidden status bar:

[image]

The the status bar on the left image is visible and on the image on the right is hidden.

My questions:

1. Why if I emulate on iPad as target: `ionic emulate ios --target="iPad-Air"` the status bar overlaps with my app  page, but when I use iPhone as target: `ionic emulate ios --target="iPhone-6-Plus"` the status bar is hidden?
2. How can I hide the status bar or at least force it not to overlap with my app screen?

I have already found some answers to modify the config.xml like this:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Try something like 
`$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    return StatusBar.hide();
  }
});`

Comment: I tried this `ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
  ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    return StatusBar.hide();
  }
});` and it didn't work.